# how to listen keydown event in android on desktop

Tags: android

I have a view that  shown in the desktop by WindowManager.addView method  from a Service Handler

Now I want to listen the 'back key down' event so that I can hide this view by WindowManager.removeView method.

I have tried binding a key listener on my view but it did  not work.

```
tipView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isShow){
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = HANDLER_ACTION_HIDE_TIP;
            mainHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I make a breakpoint on the line of "if...", but I can't see any event into here when I debug the app and on the phones desktop with pressing times of 'back key'.

So, can I do this or not  and  why?

Answer (score 0):

For the Back key press use this function instead:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  if(isShow){
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = HANDLER_ACTION_HIDE_TIP;
    mainHandler.sendMessage(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I show this view in a (background) Service, and In the Service class, there isn't a method call onBackPressed.

Comment: You can't listen to keyevents in a Service, as they do not receive KeyEvent callbacks.

Comment: But I have shown the view on the desktop, can I do something on this view to reach my goal?

Comment: The code you pasted if from the Service class- right? as is the `tipView` defined. Can't you put the onBackPressed in the activity to see if you can control parts of the created views from there?

Comment: In this situation, the main Activity was destroyed so that the onBackPressed would not work for me.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main problem, because the `Key presses` are only detected from an `Activity` (believe me I tried other means).